# BIG IP - HTTPS Health Monitor setup

Tags: load-balancing, http, https, f5-big-ip

I have a Web site that we have setup a health monitoring pages so we can take our servers in and out of the Big-IP as we see fit.  Now we have just moved onto Big-IP and the issue I have hit is that you setup Health Monitors for port 80 and 443, now the 80 check works fine but when I to get the 443 check to look at our file it fails.

Now I am aware as I am hitting the this page on the IP address over HTTPS is going to cause a cert error but I would have guessed that BIG-Ip would have been setup just to accept the cert and carry on with the check.  Is what I am wanting to do possible?

Also is there a way of just using a HTTP monitor for HTTPS?  Because if port 80 has stopped sending traffic then if i use the same monitor for 443 it will stop traffic to that.

Any help would be great!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install your cert on BIG-IP to avoid the cert error and to make the health check work for 443 : http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/tmos_management_guide_10_1/tmos_device_certif_config.html